# How to react on a message about a pending account ban on Facebook?

Tags: spam, social-engineering, phishing

Are you getting this message on chat?

> LAST WARNING : Your account is reported to have violated the policies that are considered annoying or insulting Facebook users. Until we system will disable your account within 24 hours if you do not do the reconfirmation.
>
> If you still want to use Facebook, Please confirm your account below:
>
> [redacted]-confirm-security-user.de.lv/
>
> Thanks.
>
> The Facebook Team

Comment: please help i do not want to loose my account over something i didn't do.thank you

Comment: I don't know what you expect to find here, but this site is for IT Security questions - please see the [FAQ].

Answer (score 6):

In general, you should **contact the Facebook support** or abuse team about messages like this. If the warning is real, they will be happy to confirm it. If it is not real, it is itself an abusive action and Facebook will be happy to learn about it.

In your case, the mentioned URL does not point to facebook.com but a domain that is not owned by Facebook. Therefore this message is a fake and you **should not open the address**. (Please see [What malicious things can happen when clicking on links in email?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3674/what-malicious-things-can-happen-when-clicking-on-links-in-email/3675#3675)).

The easiest thing is to just ignore it. If you have some time, you can report it to Facebook as a **phishing attempt**.

In case you already went to that page and entered your password there, make sure to change on all sites, where you used it.

Comment: Also, now is a good time for an antivirus/malware/spyware scan.

Answer (score 2):

I seriously doubt that Facebook would handle security issues through a domain named `de.lv` (that's in [Latvia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latvia)). They notoriously own a much more serious-looking `facebook.com`.

Even if they did want to deal with a "troublesome" user, I do not see why they would leave the offender 24 hours respite, and not close (or suspend) his account right away. The bit about a "reconfirmation" makes no sense whatsoever: is there any clicking that you could do, which would magically make you less "annoying and insulting" ? Last but not least, the message is written using an extremely, let's say, liberal and creative grammar. Facebook is American but that is not sufficient to explain such murdering of Shakespeare's language.

So this message has all the hallmarks of an amateurish phishing attempt. Just ignore it, it deserves nothing better.