# If most companies do not enable TLS for SMTP and IMAP, should we consider email not secure at all?

Tags: email

Many of our partner companies's email service do not enable encryption. Does that mean our email is not protected at all?

Comment: Definitely worth asking them to enable it - it will make life safer for both parties!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Email is not secure. By default, [it is not authenticated](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/9487/how-can-paypal-spoof-emails-so-easily-to-say-it-comes-from-someone-else/9498#9498). SSL/TLS on SMTP and IMAP, at best, protect the emails while in transit, not when they are at rest; and you cannot be sure that such protection has been applied.

To some extent, when sending emails within a given organization, you might know that SSL/TLS was enforced on both SMTP and IMAP, and the confidentiality issue is "just" a matter of storage on the server side. But you cannot have the same kind of guarantee when the email must cross organization boundaries.

To get proper end-to-end security for emails, look up [S/MIME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S/MIME) and [OpenPGP](http://www.openpgp.org/). The tools themselves won't ensure absolute security, because part of security is what the *users* do and understand, but at least these tools *allow* the achievement of secure emailing.