# Need to prove someone sent an email, not me

Tags: file-access

Received: by 10.182.241.38 with HTTP; Sat, 15 Mar 2014 14:09:36 -0700 (PDT)
In-Reply-To: <294B46790F860A4B9790B42606DFA3E4E4E5AE@MAHEXMB02.thrivehosted.local>
References: 
    <294B46790F860A4B9790B42606DFA3E4E4E5AE@MAHEXMB02.thrivehosted.local>
Date: Sat, 15 Mar 2014 14:09:36 -0700
Delivered-To: stevedunn2@gmail.com
Message-ID:

Comment: I don't see what this is about? How are we supposed to help you with that? All you've given us is some copied email headers.

Answer (score 2):

Though your message contents are just poorly formatted excerpts of some email headers, and not even the right ones to reach any form of conclusion, an answer can still be given:

You cannot prove that you did not send any email. Except, possibly, by proving that you were not physically capable to send anything at that time, because you were trekking on the Greenland icecap without a satellite phone, in deep coma on an hospital bed, or participating to a [conclave](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Papal_conclave) to elect a new Pope. Or maybe by arguing that the email contents are so well written and devoid of grammatical errors that you cannot possibly be the author, because that would be beyond your abilities.

Failing that, since emails are [so easy](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/9487/how-can-paypal-spoof-emails-so-easily-to-say-it-comes-from-someone-else/9498#9498) to spoof, you can *always* be considered as a potential author for any email.