# Why does a business need to secure its email system?

Tags: email, corporate-policy, smtp

Why is important for a business to secure its email system?

Comment: Are these homework questions?

Comment: IMHO it's obviously homework. For the sake of argument let's remind people that securing an email system is not subject to debate. Also, notice OP's nickname.

Comment: No just contributing to my research

Comment: What's the research about specifically? We can give you better answers if you give us more background and tell us what exactly you are researching

Comment: Your questions are FAR too broad for us to answer.

Comment: I am basically researching some points about securing IT assets for a business, so currently I am looking at different IT assets one being email systems for a organisation

Comment: oh if they are broad then its okay, don't worry, thanks for the help

Comment: How about "What are the different email securing strategies available for businesses?", it should be pretty obvious that email needs securing, I hope that's not the whole point of your research

Comment: No point is - How a business can secure its IT assets

Answer (score 3):

Email is [not secure](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/9487/how-can-paypal-spoof-emails-so-easily-to-say-it-comes-from-someone-else/9498#9498). It is not *important* for a business to "secure" its email system; it is just infeasible (by design).

Now this raises the question of how business agents will talk to each other without fearing spying, disinformation and wanton disruption from their ill-intentioned competitors. This is a hard problem. Most businesses resort to network isolation, thus splitting the network world between an *inside* (where everybody is honest and nice) and an *outside* (where roam lions and tigers and bears). For travelling agents, this isolation commonly uses a [VPN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network).

Answer (score 0):

For the same reason it's important to have a lock on your mailbox. Else anybody can pick up your mail, answer in your stead, etc.

If you have a policy where email is not secured at all by design, then don't mind putting any lock on any door.

Now if you agree that email should be secured, then you take appropriate steps, which involves either:

- Setting up your own email system, protocols for secure usage and maintenance (some users and many businesses)
- Outsource all of this (most users and many businesses)